# Firebase updateChildValue works in one case but doesn't work for the next case

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to recreate the instagram follow and unfollow functionality. When the follow button is pressed, I call the follow function in the user.swift file. The user-followers structure works perfectly but the user-following database call does not seem to work. Both have the same logic, just opposite declarations. This might sound vague but the code is self-explanatory.

user-followers structure works perfectly but user-following structure does not seem to get created at firebase.

```
class User{
    var username: String!
    var name: String!
    var profileImageUrl: String!
    var uid: String!
    var isFollowed = false

    init(uid: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
        self.uid = uid
        if let username = dictionary["username"] as? String {
            self.username = username
        }
        if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
        }
        if let profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? 
String {
            self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
        }
    }

    func follow(){
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { 
return }

        // set is followed to true
        self.isFollowed = true

        // add followed user to current user-following structure
        Database.database().reference().child("user- 
following").child(currentUid).updateChildValues([self.uid: 1])

        // add current user to followed user-follower structure
        Database.database().reference().child("user- 
followers").child(self.uid).updateChildValues([currentUid: 1])

    }

    func unfollow(){
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { 
return }

        // set is followed to false
        self.isFollowed = false

        // remove user from current user-following structure
        Database.database().reference().child("user- 
following").child(currentUid).child(self.uid).removeValue()

        // remove current user from user-follower structure
        Database.database().reference().child("user- 
followers").child(self.uid).child(currentUid).removeValue()

    }
    )
```

Comment: Is there any error message that appears on the console?

Comment: Nope, even tried using a completion and figure out if there is an error